# Create new sortable container on drag start

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have sortable rows and a row can contain columns with blocks.
The blocks inside a column are also sortable.

The goal is to sort the whole list of rows and the blocks inside of a column. And it should be also possible adding new blocks by drag’n’drop.

Sortable (rows and blocks) works without any problems:

```js
  ...
  $(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column"  // .column contains blocks
  });
  $("#manager").sortable({
    items: ".row"  // .row contains columns
  });
  ...
```

To add new blocks I have a toolbox, which holds possible new elements(rows and blocks).
If there is already a row, adding new elements works also without any problems.

```js
$(function() { 
  $(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column"
  });
  $("#manager").sortable({
    items: ".row"
  });
  $("#components div").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".column",
    helper: "clone"
  });
});
```

**But I’m not able to solve the following usecase:**

If there is no row (empty page), it should be possible to add a new block by drag’n’drop.

> This requires to add a new row while dragging the block.

Adding the new row works fine, but I’m not able to initialize the sortable on the created row when start dragging.

```js
$(function() { 
  $(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column"
  });
  $("#manager").sortable({
    items: ".row"
  });
  $("#components div").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".column",
    helper: "clone",
    start: function() {
      $("#manager").append("<div class='row'><div class='column'></div><div class='column'></div></div>")
      $(".column").sortable({
        connectWith: ".column"
      });        
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: fuchsia;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.column {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
}

.block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}

#components div {
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="manager">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column"><div class="block"></div></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column"><div class="block"></div></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="components">
    <div>Textblock</div>
</div>
```

What I tried so far, without success:

- Override internal mouseStart event of dragging --> causes problems with internal state of objects. [Check this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715748/jquery-ui-before-start-draggable).
- Add new element on mousedown event --> stopped dragging immediately