# How to check and before dropping a row inside a table

Tags: jquery

I have got two tables **table1** and **table2** 
I can drag the elements from **table1** to **table2**

Before dropping a tr, I am checking whether this **subject-id**  already exists inside **table2**  or not

If it doesn't exists inside **table2** then only I am dropping it or else doing nothing.

For this I am using the callback function recieve to check this way

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        var startTable = "table1";
        var startTable2 = "table2";
        $("tbody.connectedSortable").sortable(
        {
                connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
                items: "> tr:not(:first)",
                helper: "clone",
                cursor: "move",
                zIndex: 999990,
                start: function(event, ui)
                {
                        var start_pos = ui.item.index();
                        ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
                },
                receive: function(event, ui)
                {
                        var video_id = $(ui.item).attr('subject-id')
                        var checkerval = checkifVideoExists(video_id);

                           console.log(video_id);
                          console.log(checkerval);

                        if (checkerval)
                        {
                                return false;
                        }
                }
        });
});

function checkifVideoExists(subjectid)
{
        var flag = false;
        $('.mytable2 > tbody  > tr').each(function()
        {
                if ($(this).attr('subject-id') === "" + subjectid + "") flag = true;
                return flag;
        });
        return flag;
}
```

But this is always returning false .

Could you please let me know how to fix this ??

https://jsfiddle.net/Lphf43wd/15/

Answer (score 1):

Returning false from the each callback stops the loop. http://api.jquery.com/each/ Try this:

```
function checkifVideoExists(subjectid)
{
        var flag = false;
        $('.mytable2 > tbody  > tr').each(function()
        {
                if ($(this).attr('subject-id') === "" + subjectid + "") {
                    flag = true;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
        });
        return flag;
}
```

This fixes the specific problem you asked about.

**EDIT**

The check is being done after the drop so it always finds the dropped item. This is why the function is always returning true.

In the code below, the dropped item is passed to the checker so that it can be ignored.

Then to fix the problem that was allowing the item to be dropped, I used `sortable('cancel')` in the `receive` callback. I don't see in the docs that returning false from this callback should reject the drop.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        var startTable = "table1";
        var startTable2 = "table2";
        $("tbody.connectedSortable").sortable(
        {
                connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
                items: "> tr:not(:first)",
                helper: "clone",
                cursor: "move",
                zIndex: 999990,
                start: function(event, ui)
                {
                        var start_pos = ui.item.index();
                        ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
                },
                receive: function(event, ui)
                {
                        var video_id = $(ui.item).attr('subject-id')
                        var checkerval = checkifVideoExists(ui.item[0], video_id);

                        console.log(video_id);
                         console.log(checkerval);

                        if (checkerval) {
                            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');                        
                        }
                }
        });
});


function checkifVideoExists(elem, subjectid)
{
        var flag = false;
        $('.mytable2 > tbody  > tr').each(function()
        {
                if (elem != this && $(this).attr('subject-id') ==  subjectid  ) {
                    flag = true;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
        });
        return flag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not working i am still able to drag Maths row ...and now always value is true .

Answer (score 1):

I had quite a fun time with your question.
;)

I soon started by using [**this usefull SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16715947/2159528) to add a new event to jQuery-ui `sortable()`.
But this is not the only addition.

After having found a duplicate element on "beforeStart"...
Had to stop the drag execution and remove temporary elements that jQuery-ui had already created.

This part was particularly tricky.
I used `mouseup` event to release the element right now to stop the dragging.

Then, I *messed around a looong time* to find a way to get the `sortable()` function to its end...
It was kind of stucked with the `move` cursor on at this point...
And a click on the initial table made the original element strangely to dissapear.

I finally found that a slightly delayed (10ms) `mousedown` trigger was successfully getting it all to the stop event.

**So now**... On successfull drag, the events are:

- beforeStart
- start
- receive
- end

And duplicate element found, the events are:

- beforeStart
- start *(Here, temporary jQuery element are destroyed!)*
- end

This allows you to place some more script in the `receive` event callback, on successfull drag.
Like saving the moved data via ajax... Or anything else.

See it on this working [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/zKaZRX?editors=1011)

**Script**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // From SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/16715947/2159528
    // This is to ADD an event called "beforeStart" to ui.

    var oldMouseStart = $.ui.sortable.prototype._mouseStart;
    $.ui.sortable.prototype._mouseStart = function (event, overrideHandle, noActivation) {
        this._trigger("beforeStart", event, this._uiHash());
        oldMouseStart.apply(this, [event, overrideHandle, noActivation]);
    };
    // -- End of event extention


    var Table1 = $("#table1");
    var Table2 = $("#table2");
    var video_id="";
    var thisnewID="";
    var checkerval;

    $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        items: "tr:not(:first)",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move",
        zIndex: 999990,
        beforeStart: function (event, ui) {
            console.log("BEFORE START");
            var thisTable = $(this);

            video_id = $(ui.item).attr('subject-id');
            console.log("video_id: "+video_id);

            checkerval = checkifVideoExists(video_id, thisTable.attr("id") );

            // If an element with matching "subject-id" is found in the other table
            if (checkerval){
                $(this).trigger("mouseup"); // To release the dragged element
                setTimeout(function(){
                    thisTable.trigger("mousedown");  // To get to "stop event"... Skipping "receive" event.
                },10)
            }

        },
        start: function(event, ui){
            console.log("START");
            var thisTable = $(this);

            if (checkerval){
                var counter=0;

                thisTable.find("tr").each(function(){

                    if( $(this).hasClass("ui-sortable-placeholder") ){
                        console.log("Removing ui-placeholder");
                        $(this).addClass("remove");
                        return;
                    }

                    if( $(this).attr("subject-id")===video_id && counter==0 ){
                        console.log("Resetting display of the original element");
                        $(this).css("display","table-row");
                        counter++;
                        return;
                    }

                    if( $(this).attr("subject-id")===video_id && counter==1 ){
                        console.log("Removing ui cloned element");
                        $(this).remove();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        receive: function(event, ui){
            console.log("Receive");
            // You may place additionnal scripts here...
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            console.log("STOP");
            console.log("------------------");  // Just for console logs readability.
        }
    });


    function checkifVideoExists(video_id, thisID){
        var flag=false;

        if(thisID=="table1"){
            thisnewID="table2";
        }
        if(thisID=="table2"){
            thisnewID="table1";
        }

        $("#"+thisnewID).find('tr').each(function(){
            if ($(this).attr('subject-id') === video_id){
                console.log("Found duplicate element !");
                flag=true;
                return flag;
            }
        });
        return flag;
    }


}); // End of document ready
```